# Table rowspan adds a new column cell

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a simple table:

Code:

```css
    #page {
        background: #ffffff;
        width: 878px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        margin-top: 10px;
        display: block;
        border: 1px solid #c4c7c7;
        padding: 20px 20px 25px 20px;
        position: relative;
        z-index: 0;
        font-family: Arial;
    }

    .br {
        display: block;
        margin-bottom: 0em;
    }

    .brmedium {
        display: block;
        margin-bottom: 1em;
    }

    .brlarge {
        display: block;
        margin-bottom: 2em;
    }

    .documentTitle {
        text-align: right;
    }

    .textCenter {
        text-align: center;
    }

    .numericText {
        font-size: 26px;
        font-family: Arial;
        padding: 10px;
    }

    .square {
        width: 30px;
        height: 30px;
        border: 1px solid;
        margin: auto;
    }

    .yesNoSquare {
        width: 10px;
        height: 10px;
        border: 1px solid;
        display: inline-block;
    }


    .yesNoSquare-space {
        padding-right: 20px;
    }

    .yesNoSquare-cross {
        height: 10px;
        width: 10px;
        position: relative;
        border: 1px solid;
        display: inline-block;
    }

        .yesNoSquare-cross:after {
            position: absolute;
            top: -45px;
            bottom: 0;
            left: -1.5px;
            right: 0;
            content: "\2715"; 
            line-height: 100px;
            text-align: center;
            color: #000000;
        }

    td {
        vertical-align: top;
    }

    .tableTitle {
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 10px;
    }

    .tableText {
        font-size: 12px;
    }

    .remove-border {
        border: 0px solid #ffffff;
    }

    .commercialTable {
        border-collapse: collapse;
        width: 100%;
        /*vertical-align: top;*/
    }

    .commercialTable-space {
        padding-left: 15px;
    }

    .commercialTable tr, .commercialTable td {
        border: 1px solid #000;
        /*vertical-align: top;*/
    }

    .itemsTableHeader {
        font-size: 10px;
    }

    .itemsTableTitle {
        font-size: 16px;
    }

    .itemTableSpace {
        padding-left: 15px;
    }

    .packagingDescriptionText {
        font-size: 14px;
    }

    .alignMiddle {
        vertical-align: middle;
    }

    .footerMarkText {
        font-size: 12px;
    }

    .footerSignature {
        font-size: 14px;
    }
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="page">
    <h3 class="documentTitle">Test Test</h3>
    
    <table class="commercialTable">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="9" class="textCenter">
            <span class="tableTitle">test test test test</span>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td rowspan="2"></td>
          <td rowspan="2" class="textCenter">
            <span class="itemsTableHeader br">test. g</span>
            <span class="itemsTableHeader br">ttest</span>
          </td>
          <td colspan="3" class="textCenter">
            <span class="itemsTableHeader">17. test, test test test, test, test test test</span>
          </td>
          <td rowspan="2" class="textCenter">
            <span class="itemsTableHeader br">21</span>
            <span class="itemsTableHeader">test test</span>
          </td>
          <td rowspan="2" class="textCenter">
            <span class="itemsTableHeader br">22</span>
            <span class="itemsTableHeader">test test (lb)</span>
          </td>
          <td rowspan="2" colspan="2" class="textCenter">
            <span class="itemsTableHeader br">23</span>
            <span class="itemsTableHeader">test (test test, test test)</span>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="textCenter">
            <span class="itemsTableHeader br">18. test test</span>
            <span class="itemsTableHeader">test test</span>
          </td>
          <td class="textCenter">
            <span class="itemsTableHeader br">19. test</span>
            <span class="itemsTableHeader">test test test</span>
          </td>
          <td class="textCenter">
            <span class="itemsTableHeader br">20. test test</span>
            <span class="itemsTableHeader">(Kilos)</span>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td rowspan="2" class="numericText textCenter alignMiddle">1</td>
          <td class="alignMiddle" rowspan="2">
            <div class="square" />
          </td>
          <td class="itemsTableTitle itemTableSpace" colspan="2">test test test</td>
          <td rowspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td class="itemTableSpace">{{test}}</td>
          <td colspan="2" class="itemTableSpace">{{test}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="itemsTableTitle itemTableSpace">7318.15.50</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td rowspan="2" class="numericText textCenter alignMiddle">2</td>
          <td class="alignMiddle" rowspan="2">
            <div class="square" />
          </td>
          <td class="itemsTableTitle itemTableSpace" colspan="2">test test-test test</td>
          <td rowspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td class="itemTableSpace">{{test}}</td>
          <td colspan="2" class="itemTableSpace">{{test}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="itemsTableTitle itemTableSpace">8302.41.60</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td colspan="2"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td rowspan="2" class="numericText textCenter alignMiddle">3</td>
          <td class="alignMiddle" rowspan="2">
            <div class="square" />
          </td>
          <td class="itemsTableTitle itemTableSpace" colspan="2">test test test</td>
          <td rowspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td class="itemTableSpace">{{test}}</td>
          <td colspan="2" class="itemTableSpace">{{test}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="itemsTableTitle itemTableSpace">7318.22.00</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td colspan="2"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td rowspan="2" class="numericText textCenter alignMiddle">4</td>
          <td rowspan="2" class="alignMiddle">
            <div class="square" />
          </td>
          <td class="itemsTableTitle itemTableSpace" colspan="2">test test</td>
          <td rowspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td class="itemTableSpace">{{test}}</td>
          <td colspan="2" class="itemTableSpace">{{test}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="itemsTableTitle itemTableSpace">7318.16.45</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td rowspan="2" class="numericText textCenter alignMiddle">5</td>
          <td rowspan="2" class="alignMiddle">
            <div class="square" />
          </td>
          <td class="itemsTableTitle itemTableSpace" colspan="2">test test</td>
          <td rowspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td class="itemTableSpace">{{test}}</td>
          <td colspan="2" class="itemTableSpace">{{test}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="itemsTableTitle itemTableSpace">7318.16.45</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td rowspan="2" class="numericText textCenter alignMiddle">6</td>
          <td rowspan="2" class="alignMiddle">
            <div class="square" />
          </td>
          <td class="itemsTableTitle itemTableSpace" colspan="2">test test test test bracket</td>
          <td rowspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td class="itemTableSpace">{{test}}</td>
          <td colspan="2" class="itemTableSpace">{{test}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="itemsTableTitle itemTableSpace">8302.41.60</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td colspan="2"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td rowspan="2" class="numericText textCenter alignMiddle">7</td>
          <td rowspan="2" class="alignMiddle">
            <div class="square" />
          </td>
          <td class="itemsTableTitle itemTableSpace" colspan="2">test test test test</td>
          <td rowspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td class="itemTableSpace">{{test}}</td>
          <td colspan="2" class="itemTableSpace">{{test}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="itemsTableTitle itemTableSpace">3925.90.00</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td rowspan="2" class="numericText textCenter alignMiddle">8</td>
          <td rowspan="2" class="alignMiddle">
            <div class="square" />
          </td>
          <td class="itemsTableTitle itemTableSpace" colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
          <td rowspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td class="itemTableSpace">&nbsp;</td>
          <td colspan="2" class="itemTableSpace">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td colspan="2"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td rowspan="2" class="numericText textCenter alignMiddle">9</td>
          <td rowspan="2" class="alignMiddle">
            <div class="square" />
          </td>
          <td class="itemsTableTitle itemsTableSpace" colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
          <td rowspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td colspan="2"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="5" class="itemTableSpace">
            <span class="tableTitle br">26. test test</span>
            <span class="packagingDescriptionText br">test test test(s), test test(es), test test test(s), test test(s)</span>
          </td>
          <td colspan="2" class="itemTableSpace">
            <span class="tableTitle br">24. test test (lb)</span>
            {{test}}
          </td>
          <td class="itemTableSpace">
            <span class="tableTitle br">25. test test</span>
            {{test}}
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="3" class="itemTableSpace">
            <span class="tableTitle br">27. test test (test test)</span>
            <div class="textCenter">
              <span class="yesNoSquare"></span>
              <span class="yesNoSquare-space itemsTableHeader"> YES</span>
              <span class="yesNoSquare"></span>
              <span class="itemsTableHeader"> NO</span>
            </div>

          </td>
          <td colspan="1" class="itemTableSpace">
            <span class="tableTitle br">28. test test (test test)</span>
            <div class="textCenter">
              <div class="yesNoSquare-cross"></div>
              <span class=" yesNoSquare-space itemsTableHeader"> YES</span>
              <span class="yesNoSquare"></span>
              <span class="itemsTableHeader"> NO</span>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td class="itemTableSpace">
            <span class="tableTitle br">29. test test (test)</span>
          </td>
          <td colspan="2" class="itemTableSpace">
            <span class="tableTitle br">30. test</span>
          </td>
          <td class="itemTableSpace">
            <span class="tableTitle br">31. test test test</span>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="5" class="remove-border itemTableSpace">
          </td>
          <td colspan="2" class="itemTableSpace">
            <span class="tableTitle br">32. test</span>
          </td>
          <td class="itemTableSpace">
            <span class="tableTitle br">33. test test</span>
            {{test}}
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <p class="textCenter footerMarkText">test "X" in H.M. test test test test</p>
    <p class="footerSignature">34. test test:</p>
    <p class="footerSignature">X. test test - test test</p>
  </div>


</body>
```

Now I want to add combine 2 cells on column 21, 21 and 23 as the picture

[image]

I replaced that column  tag to:  `<td rowspan="2">&nbsp;</td>`, and it add a new column as the picture:

[image]

This happening to each rowspan I want to add

Code to replicate issue:

```css
    #page {
        background: #ffffff;
        width: 878px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        margin-top: 10px;
        display: block;
        border: 1px solid #c4c7c7;
        padding: 20px 20px 25px 20px;
        position: relative;
        z-index: 0;
        font-family: Arial;
    }

    .br {
        display: block;
        margin-bottom: 0em;
    }

    .brmedium {
        display: block;
        margin-bottom: 1em;
    }

    .brlarge {
        display: block;
        margin-bottom: 2em;
    }

    .documentTitle {
        text-align: right;
    }

    .textCenter {
        text-align: center;
    }

    .numericText {
        font-size: 26px;
        font-family: Arial;
        padding: 10px;
    }

    .square {
        width: 30px;
        height: 30px;
        border: 1px solid;
        margin: auto;
    }

    .yesNoSquare {
        width: 10px;
        height: 10px;
        border: 1px solid;
        display: inline-block;
    }


    .yesNoSquare-space {
        padding-right: 20px;
    }

    .yesNoSquare-cross {
        height: 10px;
        width: 10px;
        position: relative;
        border: 1px solid;
        display: inline-block;
    }

        .yesNoSquare-cross:after {
            position: absolute;
            top: -45px;
            bottom: 0;
            left: -1.5px;
            right: 0;
            content: "\2715"; 
            line-height: 100px;
            text-align: center;
            color: #000000;
        }

    td {
        vertical-align: top;
    }

    .tableTitle {
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 10px;
    }

    .tableText {
        font-size: 12px;
    }

    .remove-border {
        border: 0px solid #ffffff;
    }

    .commercialTable {
        border-collapse: collapse;
        width: 100%;
        /*vertical-align: top;*/
    }

    .commercialTable-space {
        padding-left: 15px;
    }

    .commercialTable tr, .commercialTable td {
        border: 1px solid #000;
        /*vertical-align: top;*/
    }

    .itemsTableHeader {
        font-size: 10px;
    }

    .itemsTableTitle {
        font-size: 16px;
    }

    .itemTableSpace {
        padding-left: 15px;
    }

    .packagingDescriptionText {
        font-size: 14px;
    }

    .alignMiddle {
        vertical-align: middle;
    }

    .footerMarkText {
        font-size: 12px;
    }

    .footerSignature {
        font-size: 14px;
    }
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="page">
    <h3 class="documentTitle">Test Test</h3>
    
    <table class="commercialTable">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="9" class="textCenter">
            <span class="tableTitle">test test test test</span>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td rowspan="2"></td>
          <td rowspan="2" class="textCenter">
            <span class="itemsTableHeader br">test. g</span>
            <span class="itemsTableHeader br">ttest</span>
          </td>
          <td colspan="3" class="textCenter">
            <span class="itemsTableHeader">17. test, test test test, test, test test test</span>
          </td>
          <td rowspan="2" class="textCenter">
            <span class="itemsTableHeader br">21</span>
            <span class="itemsTableHeader">test test</span>
          </td>
          <td rowspan="2" class="textCenter">
            <span class="itemsTableHeader br">22</span>
            <span class="itemsTableHeader">test test (lb)</span>
          </td>
          <td rowspan="2" colspan="2" class="textCenter">
            <span class="itemsTableHeader br">23</span>
            <span class="itemsTableHeader">test (test test, test test)</span>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="textCenter">
            <span class="itemsTableHeader br">18. test test</span>
            <span class="itemsTableHeader">test test</span>
          </td>
          <td class="textCenter">
            <span class="itemsTableHeader br">19. test</span>
            <span class="itemsTableHeader">test test test</span>
          </td>
          <td class="textCenter">
            <span class="itemsTableHeader br">20. test test</span>
            <span class="itemsTableHeader">(Kilos)</span>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td rowspan="2" class="numericText textCenter alignMiddle">1</td>
          <td class="alignMiddle" rowspan="2">
            <div class="square" />
          </td>
          <td class="itemsTableTitle itemTableSpace" colspan="2">test test test</td>
          <td rowspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
          <td rowspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
          <td class="itemTableSpace">{{test}}</td>
          <td colspan="2" class="itemTableSpace">{{test}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="itemsTableTitle itemTableSpace">7318.15.50</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td rowspan="2" class="numericText textCenter alignMiddle">2</td>
          <td class="alignMiddle" rowspan="2">
            <div class="square" />
          </td>
          <td class="itemsTableTitle itemTableSpace" colspan="2">test test-test test</td>
          <td rowspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td class="itemTableSpace">{{test}}</td>
          <td colspan="2" class="itemTableSpace">{{test}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="itemsTableTitle itemTableSpace">8302.41.60</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td colspan="2"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td rowspan="2" class="numericText textCenter alignMiddle">3</td>
          <td class="alignMiddle" rowspan="2">
            <div class="square" />
          </td>
          <td class="itemsTableTitle itemTableSpace" colspan="2">test test test</td>
          <td rowspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td class="itemTableSpace">{{test}}</td>
          <td colspan="2" class="itemTableSpace">{{test}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="itemsTableTitle itemTableSpace">7318.22.00</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td colspan="2"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td rowspan="2" class="numericText textCenter alignMiddle">4</td>
          <td rowspan="2" class="alignMiddle">
            <div class="square" />
          </td>
          <td class="itemsTableTitle itemTableSpace" colspan="2">test test</td>
          <td rowspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td class="itemTableSpace">{{test}}</td>
          <td colspan="2" class="itemTableSpace">{{test}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="itemsTableTitle itemTableSpace">7318.16.45</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td rowspan="2" class="numericText textCenter alignMiddle">5</td>
          <td rowspan="2" class="alignMiddle">
            <div class="square" />
          </td>
          <td class="itemsTableTitle itemTableSpace" colspan="2">test test</td>
          <td rowspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td class="itemTableSpace">{{test}}</td>
          <td colspan="2" class="itemTableSpace">{{test}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="itemsTableTitle itemTableSpace">7318.16.45</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td rowspan="2" class="numericText textCenter alignMiddle">6</td>
          <td rowspan="2" class="alignMiddle">
            <div class="square" />
          </td>
          <td class="itemsTableTitle itemTableSpace" colspan="2">test test test test bracket</td>
          <td rowspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td class="itemTableSpace">{{test}}</td>
          <td colspan="2" class="itemTableSpace">{{test}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="itemsTableTitle itemTableSpace">8302.41.60</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td colspan="2"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td rowspan="2" class="numericText textCenter alignMiddle">7</td>
          <td rowspan="2" class="alignMiddle">
            <div class="square" />
          </td>
          <td class="itemsTableTitle itemTableSpace" colspan="2">test test test test</td>
          <td rowspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td class="itemTableSpace">{{test}}</td>
          <td colspan="2" class="itemTableSpace">{{test}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="itemsTableTitle itemTableSpace">3925.90.00</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td rowspan="2" class="numericText textCenter alignMiddle">8</td>
          <td rowspan="2" class="alignMiddle">
            <div class="square" />
          </td>
          <td class="itemsTableTitle itemTableSpace" colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
          <td rowspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td class="itemTableSpace">&nbsp;</td>
          <td colspan="2" class="itemTableSpace">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td colspan="2"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td rowspan="2" class="numericText textCenter alignMiddle">9</td>
          <td rowspan="2" class="alignMiddle">
            <div class="square" />
          </td>
          <td class="itemsTableTitle itemsTableSpace" colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
          <td rowspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td colspan="2"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="5" class="itemTableSpace">
            <span class="tableTitle br">26. test test</span>
            <span class="packagingDescriptionText br">test test test(s), test test(es), test test test(s), test test(s)</span>
          </td>
          <td colspan="2" class="itemTableSpace">
            <span class="tableTitle br">24. test test (lb)</span>
            {{test}}
          </td>
          <td class="itemTableSpace">
            <span class="tableTitle br">25. test test</span>
            {{test}}
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="3" class="itemTableSpace">
            <span class="tableTitle br">27. test test (test test)</span>
            <div class="textCenter">
              <span class="yesNoSquare"></span>
              <span class="yesNoSquare-space itemsTableHeader"> YES</span>
              <span class="yesNoSquare"></span>
              <span class="itemsTableHeader"> NO</span>
            </div>

          </td>
          <td colspan="1" class="itemTableSpace">
            <span class="tableTitle br">28. test test (test test)</span>
            <div class="textCenter">
              <div class="yesNoSquare-cross"></div>
              <span class=" yesNoSquare-space itemsTableHeader"> YES</span>
              <span class="yesNoSquare"></span>
              <span class="itemsTableHeader"> NO</span>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td class="itemTableSpace">
            <span class="tableTitle br">29. test test (test)</span>
          </td>
          <td colspan="2" class="itemTableSpace">
            <span class="tableTitle br">30. test</span>
          </td>
          <td class="itemTableSpace">
            <span class="tableTitle br">31. test test test</span>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="5" class="remove-border itemTableSpace">
          </td>
          <td colspan="2" class="itemTableSpace">
            <span class="tableTitle br">32. test</span>
          </td>
          <td class="itemTableSpace">
            <span class="tableTitle br">33. test test</span>
            {{test}}
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <p class="textCenter footerMarkText">test "X" in H.M. test test test test</p>
    <p class="footerSignature">34. test test:</p>
    <p class="footerSignature">X. test test - test test</p>
  </div>


</body>
```

I do not understand why is adding a new column, what am I doing wrong? Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I stripped away all of the code except what is directly relevant to the issue and it appears that the table row/columns are rendering as expected.

I created a diagram on top of a screenshot of the code to better explain my observation. (Note that the color of the squares/rectangles do not have any significance, they were only chosen to visually differentiate the various lines of code.) Each color square/rectangle in the first row has a matching color in the second row to visually show the association between the table columns in each row.

[image: HTML table code diagram]

Essentially in the first row you are creating 9 columns. Four of the columns in the first row have rowspans equalling 2 which leaves 5 columns that the second row must then take into account.

So if you don't want that extra column to appear at the end of the second row, the last td of the first row should not have a colspan and the last td of the second row should be removed.

When trying to debug lengthy HTML I recommend eliminating all HTML/CSS that is not directly related to the problem, pinpoint the issue and then incrementally add back code while frequently testing only once the issue has been definitively fixed.